# Get index of letter in word in list - python

Tags: python

I have a long list with a lot of words and I want to create new list with just the words
that start with "a".

```py
list_1 = []

for i in range(len(words) - 1):
    if words[0: len(words) - 1][0] == "a":
        list_1.append(words)

print(list_1)
```

Comment: I see you have included some code in your question. Does this code work for you? Does it produce any errors at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
list_1= [word for word in words if word[0] =='a']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `startswith`

```
list_1 = [x for x in words if x.startswith('a')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 -

```
list_1 = []

for i in range(len(words) - 1):
    if words[i][0] == "a":
        list_1.append(words)

print(list_1)
```

Method 2

```
list_1= [word for i in words if word[0] =='a']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
old_list = ['hello', 'world', 'alike', 'algorithm']
new_list = [i for i in old_list if i.startswith('a')]
```

Now printing the new_list will give
['alike', 'algorithm']

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
for i in range(len(words) - 1):
    if words[0] == "a":
        list_1.append(words)

print(list_1)
```